# Issues with xRDP and ubuntu server

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

I installed the following packages in the following order

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

When trying to connect to `sesman-xvnc` I'm getting the following:

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5911
error - problem connecting
```

I have been trying various solutions online for several days already, I'd appreciate any help here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

xRDP and Ubuntu 16.04.x does not go along quite well.  This is because the default xrdp package available in Ubuntu repository is quite obsolete (the current version is 0.9.11, the one in Ubuntu 16.04x repository is something like 0.6)

xrdp version 0.6 does not work with Unity Desktop.  So you have two options

**Option A - use xrdp 0.6 but install alternate desktop environment**

You have to install another Desktop interface on top of your Ubuntu machine (can be xfce or mate-desktop). Then you have to create the ~/.xsession file that is used to start the xfce or mate-desktop session while performing a remote connection

More info at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952

**Option B - Use this script to compile from source and connect to Unity**

If you feel adventurous, you can use the following script to automate your installation and have the latest xrdp version installed which will allow you to connect to Unity Desktop....Performance are not great on Ubuntu 16.04 but it's still workable....

Please read the instructions and download the script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11719

Hope this help 
Till next Time